# How to implement social login (with Google etc.) with an SPA and ASP.NET Core using OpenIdDict?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, openiddict

I am trying to understand what the best way is to implement third party authorization (login with Google / with Microsoft / ...) with a SPA and an ASP.NET Core backend that uses OpenIdDict.

Currently I have a SPA (Angular) that can get access and refresh-tokens using username and password from the ASP.NET Core backend and then use the access-token for API requests on the backend.

I would like to allow the user to login with his Google/Microsoft account.

I am using OpenIdDict and I implemented a connect/token endpoint.

What is the intended way to implement this with OpenIdDict?

I am not sure if I am heading in the correct direction. Currently, I am getting an access token for the Microsoft account on the SPA using authentication code flow with PKCE. I want to use that access token to get my own access + refresh token by calling an endpoint from my backend. On this endpoint I can check if the Microsoft access token is valid, get information about the user and create a local user if not existing and return my tokens.

[Login Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1jn4.png)

Am I doing something unusual here? I feel like I am missing something simple because this should be a common use case but I seem to not find any samples.

OpenIdDict is restrictive in creating tokens only from endpoints that are intended for that by default.

```cs
// I cannot return this SignInResult from any endpoint
return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

I think OpenIdDict is restrictive for a good reason and I think that I should not work around these restrictions.

**Alternative Flow**

I could also start the authentication code flow from the backend similar to a regular web app (non-SPA) but then I would need to let the 3rd party redirect the user to the SPA and do an additional request in order to be able to get the tokens. I don't think that I should do that and the problem remains.

[Authentication Code Flow with strange redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zBCY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do the authentication with the External Identity Providers like Microsoft, Google and ... you'll end up with a pair of Identity and Access Tokens in your SPA. Then you'll need to have a custom OAuth flow implemented in your server side, similar to User Credentials Flow but instead of username and password, you need to receive an Identity Token and a Provider name.
Then you must validate the Identity Token with the provider and if it is valid, you can return the SiginIn Result with the OpenIddict Scheme which triggers OpenIddict to generate the access token.

A better way in my opinion is to do it all in the server.

So your server is also an OpenId Connect server and you start an Authorization Code flow from your SPA to your server.

Your server finds out that the user is not authenticated, so it will redirect the user to a login page in the server (it also passes the current URL as a ReturnUrl to the login page).

Inside this login page you can have a login with Microsoft button or whatever just to login the user. (ASP.NET Core has the appropriate middleware for common Providers like Microsoft, Google, ... so it is pretty easy).

After the login is successfully done with Microsoft and the user is returned to your server (not your SPA because your serve is acting as a oauth client here), the server sees that ReturnUrl from the previous step and goes back to the authorize endpoint again but this time the user is authenticated and OpenIddict can happily return an Authorization Code to the client which started the authorization code flow and that is your SPA!

Finally your SPA will exchange that code with an access token from the server.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot. I think that I managed to implement the flow like you suggested. However I am unsure about one step: After Microsoft redirects back to my backend with the authorization code, I redirect back to my authorize endpoint. I authenticate by `return Results.SignIn(principal, properties, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` and in authorize I am checking `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`. It seems a little bit strange to me that I also need Cookies here.

Comment: @DavidHübscher You said that you are redirecting the user to your authorize endpoint so you need that cookie! anyway, if you have that cookie, the user will stay signed in to your server, and this can be used to issue tokens for the next time that the user needs new tokens! It's  seems strange because your Identity Service and Your API are the same :) while in big apps we usually separate them! e.g. Microsoft that has accounts.microsoft.com, google has accounts.google.com ,...